# Why does Rust emit 280 lines of assembly code to print "Hello, world"?

Tags: macos, assembly, rust

A simple 3-line Hello, World program in Rust emits a 280 line assembly file in order to print two words. Meanwhile, [a pure assembly version of this program](https://gist.github.com/FiloSottile/7125822) only takes ~15 lines. Why is the Rust version so much longer?

This is on Mac OS.

**`hello.rs`**:

```
fn main() {
    println!("hello world")
}
```

**`hello.s`** (generated by `rustc --emit=asm hello.rs`):

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 7
    .private_extern __ZN3std2rt10lang_start17hb4e01c1e588bf694E
    .globl  __ZN3std2rt10lang_start17hb4e01c1e588bf694E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN3std2rt10lang_start17hb4e01c1e588bf694E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    leaq    l___unnamed_1(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, -24(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rcx
    callq   __ZN3std2rt19lang_start_internal17hcf96e32a124891dcE
    movq    %rax, -32(%rbp)
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17h275cd8632ff3ab7dE:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    callq   *(%rdi)
    callq   __ZN54_$LT$$LP$$RP$$u20$as$u20$std..process..Termination$GT$6report17hf5e270b394827df3E
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN3std3sys4unix7process14process_common8ExitCode6as_i3217h7e671b2505e0c229E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN4core3fmt9Arguments6new_v117h39ef65f250941772E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    movq    $0, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, (%rdi)
    movq    %rdx, 8(%rdi)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    %rdx, 16(%rdi)
    movq    %rsi, 24(%rdi)
    movq    %rcx, 32(%rdi)
    movq    %r8, 40(%rdi)
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce40call_once$u7b$$u7b$vtable.shim$u7d$$u7d$17h61f8ee8d3fead017E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    (%rdi), %rdi
    callq   __ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h47f538be1b10688dE
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce9call_once17h47f538be1b10688dE:
Lfunc_begin0:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 155, _rust_eh_personality
    .cfi_lsda 16, Lexception0
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $48, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -32(%rbp)
Ltmp0:
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17h275cd8632ff3ab7dE
Ltmp1:
    movl    %eax, -36(%rbp)
    jmp LBB5_1
LBB5_1:
    jmp LBB5_2
LBB5_2:
    movl    -36(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
LBB5_3:
    jmp LBB5_4
LBB5_4:
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __Unwind_Resume
    ud2
LBB5_5:
Ltmp2:
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -8(%rbp)
    jmp LBB5_3
Lfunc_end0:
    .cfi_endproc
    .section    __TEXT,__gcc_except_tab
    .p2align    2
GCC_except_table5:
Lexception0:
    .byte   255
    .byte   255
    .byte   1
    .uleb128 Lcst_end0-Lcst_begin0
Lcst_begin0:
    .uleb128 Ltmp0-Lfunc_begin0
    .uleb128 Ltmp1-Ltmp0
    .uleb128 Ltmp2-Lfunc_begin0
    .byte   0
    .uleb128 Ltmp1-Lfunc_begin0
    .uleb128 Lfunc_end0-Ltmp1
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
Lcst_end0:
    .p2align    2

    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN4core3ptr18real_drop_in_place17h0ab16307507408dbE:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN54_$LT$$LP$$RP$$u20$as$u20$std..process..Termination$GT$6report17hf5e270b394827df3E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    callq   __ZN68_$LT$std..process..ExitCode$u20$as$u20$std..process..Termination$GT$6report17h03f2ed18f1614f97E
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN68_$LT$std..process..ExitCode$u20$as$u20$std..process..Termination$GT$6report17h03f2ed18f1614f97E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movb    %dil, -1(%rbp)
    leaq    -1(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZN3std3sys4unix7process14process_common8ExitCode6as_i3217h7e671b2505e0c229E
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
__ZN5hello4main17hef70db39c48df377E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $48, %rsp
    leaq    l___unnamed_2(%rip), %rax
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %r8d
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movl    $1, %edx
    movl    $8, %ecx
    callq   __ZN4core3fmt9Arguments6new_v117h39ef65f250941772E
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZN3std2io5stdio6_print17hd8f597a6d310dad5E
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  _main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movslq  %edi, %rax
    leaq    __ZN5hello4main17hef70db39c48df377E(%rip), %rdi
    movq    %rsi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    callq   __ZN3std2rt10lang_start17hb4e01c1e588bf694E
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    __DATA,__const
    .p2align    3
l___unnamed_1:
    .quad   __ZN4core3ptr18real_drop_in_place17h0ab16307507408dbE
    .quad   8
    .quad   8
    .quad   __ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17h275cd8632ff3ab7dE
    .quad   __ZN3std2rt10lang_start28_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$17h275cd8632ff3ab7dE
    .quad   __ZN4core3ops8function6FnOnce40call_once$u7b$$u7b$vtable.shim$u7d$$u7d$17h61f8ee8d3fead017E

    .section    __TEXT,__const
l___unnamed_3:
    .ascii  "hello world\n"

    .section    __DATA,__const
    .p2align    3
l___unnamed_2:
    .quad   l___unnamed_3
    .asciz  "\f\000\000\000\000\000\000"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: Can you compile with optimizations on?

Comment: I get [19 lines](https://godbolt.org/z/Y67REJ) including blanks, so one less than your pure assembly version.

Comment: why not ? I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Stargateur I never said there was a problem — just trying to figure out why it’s so long.

Comment: @Jmb How does that website generate the assembly output?

Comment: @Michael Petch Is that a flag to rustc?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the option `-O` as a command line option to `rustc`

Comment: @jmb I get 1301 lines for your example if I turn off off all the options for hiding stuff so the complete assembly output is shown: https://godbolt.org/z/_Pu632

Comment: @RossRidge: much of that is debug metadata because Godbolt passes an option to enable that.  (For its colour highlighting to match asm and source lines.)  But yes, good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When compiling code there are a lot of potential trade-offs that a compiler could make between different aspects, such as:

- Code size
- Run time performance
- Memory used
- Ease of debugging
- Compilation time

Most compilers will offer you some way to specify how you want these trade-offs to be considered. rustc is no exception - you can use the [opt-level](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#opt-level) code generation option to specify what you want:

> opt-level This flag lets you control the optimization level.
>
> 0: no optimizations, also turn on cfg(debug_assertions).
>
> 1: basic optimizations
>
> 2: some optimizations
>
> 3: all optimizations
>
> s: optimize for binary size
>
> z: optimize for binary size, but also turn off loop vectorization.

For example you could specify `-C opt-level=3` for maximum performance optimizations (which would also increase compilation time in most cases).

The rustc option `-O` is shorthand for `-C opt-level=3`.

As per the [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/Y67REJ) supplied by @jbm, with -O you get 19 lines of assembly.

Also note that most people do not call rustc directly, rather they use cargo as a build control tool. The [`cargo build`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html) subcommand allows you to specify a build profile which determines things such as the optimization level applied. The `--release` flag invokes an optimized profile suitable for release builds.